# ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I'm copying a script, and it seems to be not having any syntax error.
But every time I compile it, error occurs from the scanf.
Why does this occur? and how can I fix this script?

my coding environment is replit.com

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a1[101][101], a2[101][101]; //치즈
int n, m;

void copy() { //a2를 a1과 같은 모양으로
  int i, j;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
      a1[i][j] = a2[i][j];
}

void fill1(int x, int y) { //초기에 바깥공기인 칸들의 값을 2로 만든다.
  if (x < 1 || y < 1 || x > n || y > m)
    return;
  if (a1[x][y] == 0) {
    a1[x][y] = 2;
    fill1(x + 1, y);
    fill1(x - 1, y);
    fill1(x, y + 1);
    fill1(x, y - 1);
  }
}

void fill2(int x, int y) { //fill1과 같음, 그러나 a2 치즈에 대한 코드
  if (x < 1 || y < 1 || x > n || y > m)
    return;
  if (a2[x][y] == 0) {
    a2[x][y] = 2;
    fill2(x + 1, y);
    fill2(x-1, y);
    fill2(x, y + 1);
    fill2(x, y-1);
  }
}

void fill3(int x, int y) { //c로 표지됐던 치즈 칸이나, 새롭게 연결된 빈 공기 간들을 바깥공기 2로 만든다
  if (x < 1 || y < 1 || x > n || y > m)
    return;
  if (a1[x][y] == 3 || a1[x][y] == 0) {
    a1[x][y] = 2;
    fill3(x + 1, y);
    fill3(x - 1, y);
    fill3(x, y + 1);
    fill3(x, y - 1);
  }
}

int check(int x, int y) { //치즈 한 칸이 바깥공기랑 만나는 면이 몇 개인가요?
  int t = 0;
  if (a1[x + 1][y] == 2) //치즈의 오른쪽이 바깥공기인가요?
    t++;
  if (a1[x - 1][y] == 2) //치즈의 왼쪽이 바깥공기인가요?
    t++;
  if (a1[x][y + 1] == 2) //치즈의 위쪽이 바깥공기인가요?
    t++;
  if (a1[x][y - 1] == 2) //치즈의 아래쪽이 바깥공기인가요?
    t++;
  return t;
}

int main() {
  int i, j, hour = 0, count;
  scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
  for (i = 1;i <= n; i++)
    for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &a1[i][j]);
      a2[i][j] = a1[i][j];
    }
  fill3(1, 1);
  
  while (1) {
    count = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
        if (a1[i][j] == 1 && check(i, j) >= 2) {
          a2[i][j] = 0;
          count++;
        }
      }
    if (count == 0) {
      printf("%d", hour); break;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        if (a1[i][j] == 1 && a2[i][j] == 0)
          fill2(i, j);
    hour++;
    copy();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

error:

> ./main.cpp:64:3: error: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Werror,-Wunused-result]
> scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
> ^~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ./main.cpp:67:7: error: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Werror,-Wunused-result]
> scanf("%d", &a1[i][j]);
> ^~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 2 errors generated.
> make: *** [Makefile:10: main] Error 1

I couldn't expect which part is problem

Comment: You're not using the return value from `scanf`. You should since it returns the number of items converted so you know if it was successful or not. `if (scanf("%d %d", &n, &m) != 2) { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: Are you sure this is meant to be C++ code, and not C?

Comment: You compile with `-Wunused-result` option, which produces a warning when a return value of `scanf` is not checked. And you also compile with `-Werror` option, that turns warnings into errors.

Answer (score 2):

The error is technically not an error, just a warning.

The function `scanf` returns a value and you're getting a warning that you're not using it, because you run the compiler with this flag:

> -Wunused-result

You also use this flag:

> -Werror

That elevates all warnings to errors.

To solve this, either

a) Check the return value by saving it into a variable or directly putting it into an if, to verify it works as expected.

b)
Actively tell the compiler that you don't want to use the return value (grossly simplified, but works)

> std::ignore = scanf(...);

c)
Remove the flag that warns you about unused return values

d)
Remove the flag that elevates errors (absolutely not recommended, but it will solve your problem)

Comment: Most definitely prefer to check the value. In general, unchecked and unhandled result codes typically turn into bugs. Not checking the return code of an IO transaction is one of the easiest ways to increase the amount of debugging you have to do. Users are terrible input sources, whether they're simply inputting typos or because they are malicious <expletive deleted>s deliberately trying to break the program. Never trust a user.